# auto increment by group in list object python

Tags: python

```
[{'id': '1', 'nama': 'fajar'},  {'id': '2', 'nama': 'fajar'},  
 {'id': '3', 'nama': 'fajar'},  {'id': '4', 'nama': 'fajar'},  
 {'id': '5', 'nama': 'sita'},  {'id': '6', 'nama': 'lia'},  
 {'id': '7', 'nama': 'indra'},  {'id': '8', 'nama': 'indra'},  
 {'id': '9', 'nama': 'indra'},  {'id': '10', 'nama': 'indra'}]
```

Is there a way to add the numbers in the column name with autoincremnt by group name? my expected result is like this:

> fajar 0
>
> fajar 1
>
> fajar 2
>
> fajar 3
>
> sita 1
>
> lia 1
>
> indra 0
>
> indra 1
>
> indra 2
>
> indra 3
>
> indra 4

thanks

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Column name... It is a list of dictionnary. How do you create it?

Comment: Can you give an example output that you want?

Comment: i try to insert increment in name, but the increment by group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also not sure if I see what you mean. Furthermore if I follow your example, should this not be sita and lia with a `0` and not `1`? indra and fajar start with `0`, too.

Anyhow. This might help:

```
d = [{'id': '1', 'nama': 'fajar'}, {'id': '2', 'nama': 'fajar'}, {'id': '3', 'nama': 'fajar'}, {'id': '4', 'nama': 'fajar'}, {'id': '5', 'nama': 'sita'}, {'id': '6', 'nama': 'lia'}, {'id': '7', 'nama': 'indra'}, {'id': '8', 'nama': 'indra'}, {'id': '9', 'nama': 'indra'}, {'id': '10', 'nama': 'indra'}]
c = {}
for i in d:
    if not i["nama"] in c:
        c[i["nama"]] = 0
    c[i["nama"]] += 1
    i["nama"] += str(c[i["nama"]] - 1)
```

gives

```
[{'id': '1', 'nama': 'fajar0'},
 {'id': '2', 'nama': 'fajar1'},
 {'id': '3', 'nama': 'fajar2'},
 {'id': '4', 'nama': 'fajar3'},
 {'id': '5', 'nama': 'sita0'},
 {'id': '6', 'nama': 'lia0'},
 {'id': '7', 'nama': 'indra0'},
 {'id': '8', 'nama': 'indra1'},
 {'id': '9', 'nama': 'indra2'},
 {'id': '10', 'nama': 'indra3'}]
```

Comment: i mean like this

[{'id': '1', 'nama': 'fajar0'},

 {'id': '2', 'nama': 'fajar1'},
 {'id': '3', 'nama': 'fajar2'},
 {'id': '4', 'nama': 'fajar3'},
 {'id': '5', 'nama': 'sita0'},
 {'id': '6', 'nama': 'lia0'},
 {'id': '7', 'nama': 'indra1'},
 {'id': '8', 'nama': 'indra2'},
 {'id': '9', 'nama': 'indra3'},
 {'id': '10', 'nama': 'indra3'}]

can like that? im so appreciate yout answer :D

Comment: I've updated the example. Still there must be  an error in your example. id 7 (indra) should start with `0`. This error continues. You should really be more conscientious. You expect proper answers from your peers, don't you?